# Zxing can´t scan code 128

Tags: android, zxing, code128

I try to write android app which scan code in code128 format.

I use Zxing library, which support it.

Another scan work properly.

I use this code to start scanner:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    //intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_128");
    startActivityForResult(intent, SCAN_TYPE_POSITION);
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you for answers

Comment: What do you get in logs?

Comment: Nothing when I target on code128. Any other scan with PRODUCT_MODE work normally. But this is not work and in log is nothing. @PrerakSola

Answer (score 0):

```
public void scanBar(View v) {
    try {

        //start the scanning activity from the com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_128");

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

        //on catch, show the download dialog
        showDialog(Barcode2Activity.this, "Ñão foi encontrado scanner de código de barras", "Deseja realizar o Download?", "Sim", "Não").show();

    }
}
```